# Operator on Hilbert space restricted to orthogonal complement

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a compact self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. If $(e_n)_n$ is an orthonormal system of eigenvectors then  setting $H_0= \{ z : \langle z , e_n \rangle=0$ forall $n$ $\}$, we have $T(H_0)=0$.

My attempt:

If $H_0=0$ then clearly we are done. So assume otherwise. If $z\in H_0$, $\langle Tz,e_n\rangle =0$. Hence, $T(H_0)\subseteq H_0$. So, $T|_{H_0}:H_0\rightarrow H_0$ is a compact, self adjoint operator. Note $H_0$ is closed in $H$.

Since $T|_{H_0}$ is compact and self adjoint, assume wlog that $||T|_{H_0}||$ is an eigenvalue, with corresponding eigen vector $w$.

Now, I'm trying to show that $||T|_{H_0}||=0$, but am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you saying that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ then $v \bot H_0$? if that is the case the spectral theorem has something to say.

Comment: If $\{e_n\}$ consists of all mutually orthogonal eigenvectors, including the ones corresponding to $0,$ then $H_0=\{0\}.$